# how to iterate a 8 letters, and i want them to iterate in length and content? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am Trying to code a Scrabble solver in python. i want to iterate a 8 letters and want them to iterate in length like this?

> z="asdfghjk
>
> (some code)
>
> print (iterations)
>
> (as,ad,af,ag,ah,.....sa,sadf,fgh,)
>
> Every possible length and possible arrangement of letter from 1-8 letter long.

Comment: Any code to complement this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy with itertools.combinations.

```
from itertools import combinations
from math import factorial as fac  # extra

z = "asdfghjk"
n = len(z)  # extra
for i in range(1, 9):
    print("{} of {}, {} combinations".
          format(i, n, fac(n) // (fac(i)*fac(n-i))))  # extra
    for combo in combinations(z, i):
        print(''.join(combo), end = ', ')
    print('\n')  # extra
```

The lines marked '# extra' are non-essential and only added for a nice display.

```
1 of 8, 8 combinations
a, s, d, f, g, h, j, k, 

2 of 8, 28 combinations
as, ad, af, ag, ah, aj, ak, sd, sf, sg, sh, sj, sk, df, ...

(etc)

7 of 8, 8 combinations
asdfghj, asdfghk, asdfgjk, asdfhjk, asdghjk, asfghjk, adfghjk, sdfghjk, 

8 of 8, 1 combinations
asdfghjk,
```

Comment: How would i save the combinations in a list?

Comment: append instead of print.

Comment: You said "Every possible length and possible arrangement of letter from 1-8 letter long" -- that's permutation not combination as the way I read your initial problem statement.  You can look here for more:  https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use the itertools library to accomplish this goal:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> letters = 'abc'
>>> combinations = set()
>>>
>>> for i in range(len(letters)):
...     combinations.update(
...        [''.join(x) for x in itertools.permutations(letters, i + 1)])
>>>
>>> for combination in sorted(combinations):
...     print(combination)
a
ab
abc
ac
acb
b
ba
bac
bc
bca
c
ca
cab
cb
cba
```

This shows for 1 thru 3 combinations -- just update to number of characters and range to 8 for all possible permutations 1 thru 8.

Comment: This solution handles things like "letters='aba'", though the for loop should be "for i in range (len(letters)):"

Answer (score 0):

Your example is not a good example of your statement of the problem (Scrabble)
. In your example, you are assuming that each letter is unique in your set of tiles. You have also left out the single letter instances. At this point the "itertools" answers have fallen into the trap that you laid with your examples.

For example, assume that you held 8 A's (I don't remember what the max numbers are of each letter off-hand). Then the possible combinations are 8. A, AA, ... AAAAAAAA.